# Edit shortcut list window displayed through super-key pressing

Tags: unity, shortcuts

When I long press super key in Ubuntu, it's displayed a list of keyboard shortcuts used in unity. I would like to know if it's possible to edit the content of this window to display something different of keyboard shortcuts (for example codes used in my job that I use often).

Is the content of keyboard shortcuts windows stored in some text file? Or is it stored as a image? Would I be able to edit it to display anything I want?

Comment: Cool idea, but I don't think its possable.

Comment: Why is this question being voted for closing?

Comment: @EricCarvalho: For what it's worth, I think it should be left open.

Answer (score 2):

This is currently not possible unless you edit the source code of Unity and implement it yourself.